# Include View-Specific Scripts with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

relatively new to Angular so I'm not sure what the best practice is for this scenario.  I have a fairly simple index.html that include an ng-view in the middle.  Later on in the html I need to include page(view)-specific js scripts after some of the generic app-level scripts load.  What is the best practice for doing so?

Pseudo-Code

[ng-view]

[generic stuff for all pages]

[view-specific scripts]

Comment: please add more detail to your question

Answer (score 0):

By default AngularJS needs all the script related to your ng-app module loaded at one go, which is called bootstrapping the app. What this means is that if the scripts are related to AngularJS such as controller, directives and service, routes have to be loaded together in the script block, they cannot be loaded on demand.

There are some plugin that allow lazy loading such as these

https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers

https://github.com/nikospara/angular-require-lazy

https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad